# How to round a rollup SQL Query?

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

How can I do a round on a rollup like I round or sum a function?

```
ROUND(SUM(T.TICKET_PRICE),2)
```

for example:

```
SELECT EmpId, Yr, SUM(Sales) AS Sales
FROM Sales
GROUP BY EmpId, Yr WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: Are you trying to round only on the rollup value or on all values?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing I can think of is -

```
SELECT EmpId, Yr,
       CASE WHEN EmpId IS NULL AND Yr IS NULL
            THEN ROUND(SUM(Sales))
            ELSE SUM(Sales)
       END AS Sales
FROM Sales
GROUP BY EmpId, Yr WITH ROLLUP
```

Unfortunately, this only works reliably if `EmpId` and `Yr` are `NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Put the rollup in a subquery:

```
SELECT R.EmpID, R.Yr, ROUND(R.Sales,2) AS Sales
FROM (
    SELECT EmpId, Yr, SUM(Sales) AS Sales
    FROM Sales
    GROUP BY EmpId, Yr WITH ROLLUP) R
```

Answer (score 0):

You were so close, just wrap your sum with the round function.

```
SELECT EmpId, Yr, round(SUM(Sales),2) AS Sales
FROM Sales
GROUP BY EmpId, Yr
```